# Load content while scrolling using waypoints plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I use the plugin waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)

**EDIT : working solution : http://pastebin.com/x95Qf7m8 **

What I'm trying to do is to load the share widget contained in my link when the "share-this" tag is scrolled down.

You may notice the use of head.ready which is just a replacement of document.ready as I use headjs to load my external scripts.

My question is simple, why is it working when triggered by a click, but not using the waypoint plugin ? Any help would be welcome

My website : http://www.entendu.info

```
head.ready(function() {


$('.share-this').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
   if (direction === 'down') {

    var contentId = $('.share-this').attr('rel');
    var uri = $('.share-this').attr('rev');

    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log('clicked');

    $.ajax({
   url: 'http://www.entendu.info/share',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'html',
   data: {id:contentId, url:uri},
   complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {

   },
   success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

   $('#'+contentId).html(data);
   },
   error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

   }
   });

   }
   else {

      // do this on the way back up through the waypoint
   }



   });



});




<div class="content" id="{$posts[i].PID}" style="float:left">
<a href="" class="share-this" rel="{$posts[i].PID}" rev={$posts[i].name|escape:'htmlall'}">

<img src="{$imageurl}/share2.png" width="379" height="22" style="opacity: 0.5; float:left"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function you say `e.preventDefault()` but there is no `e`. Your event is named `event`.  If you look in your console you will see the error "e is not defined". Plus, preventing default within a waypoint handler does nothing, so I'm not sure what the point of that line is anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! And sorry for my beginner mistake !
Do you know how I could make it to load when it first appear, because right now the buttons are loaded but when they are scrolled down (and not visible anymore), What I would like is that the buttons load just when the div appears at the bottom of the screen
(something like using offset ?)

Comment: I fixed my problem using offset : "85%"
But I have another question (never ending) IF the user scroll directly to the bottom, most of the waypoint ain't triggered, only the 2 first one and the last one, as if the middle ones are scrolled too fast.. Any help ?